# In QueryDSL is it possible to use count(*) in where clause

Tags: querydsl

I'm currently working on an aggregated query and would like to convert the following query to QueryDSL. Basically what it does is aggregate all the products sold for a given category and get the category with count > x.

```
select
    tcc.catcode, tcc.catcount 
from 
    (select 
        g.code catcode, count(*) catcount
    from dwh_aggregated_order a
        join cat_product_category g on g.id=a.product_category_id
    group by g.code) tcc
where tcc.catcount > 2
```

Comment: I don't know QueryDSL, but what you wrote looks like valid ANSI SQL to me.  What is the origin of your question about including `COUNT(*)` in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Yes, this is a valid SQL in fact I already tested it. But I want to convert it to QueryDSL.

Comment: Here, have an upvote.  But sadly I don't know QueryDSL.

Answer (score 2):

I think the query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT g.code               AS catcode
FROM   dwh_aggregated_order AS a
INNER JOIN cat_product_category g ON g.id = a.product_category_id
GROUP BY g.code
HAVING COUNT(g.code) > 2;
```

Then in querydsl you could use `.having(g.code.count().gt(2L))`